# Eliminate all text before specific character in output loop using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have data that looks like this:

```
['6005600401']
['000000: PUSH1 0x05']
['000002: PUSH1 0x04']
['000004: ADD']
```

The initial representation it's derived from is here:

```
6005600401
000000: PUSH1 0x05
000002: PUSH1 0x04
000004: ADD
```

The output I'd like to create is like so:

```
PUSH1 0x60, PUSH1 0x40, MSTORE, CALLDATASIZE, ISZERO, PUSH2 0x006c, JUMPI, PUSH1 0xe0, PUSH1 0x02, EXP, PUSH1 0x00, CALLDATALOAD, DIV
```

I've been experimenting with different techniques of isolating that data in the python shell like so:

```
>>> date_div = "Blah blah blah, Updated: Aug. 23, 2012"
>>> date_div.split('Updated: ')
['Blah blah blah, ', 'Aug. 23, 2012']
>>> date_div.split('Updated: ')[-1]
'Aug. 23, 2012'
>>> line = ['000000: PUSH1 0x05']
>>> date_div.split(':')
['Blah blah blah, Updated', ' Aug. 23, 2012']
>>> line.split(':')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
>>> line = ["000000: PUSH1 0x05"]
>>> line.split(':')
```

But as of yet I've not been able to eliminate all the superfluous characters. How can I employ regex such that my data goes from a representation like this:

```
['6005600401']
['000000: PUSH1 0x05']
['000002: PUSH1 0x04']
['000004: ADD']
```

Yo one like this:

```
PUSH1 0x60, PUSH1 0x40, MSTORE, CALLDATASIZE, ISZERO, PUSH2 0x006c, JUMPI, PUSH1 0xe0, PUSH1 0x02, EXP, PUSH1 0x00, CALLDATALOAD, DIV
```

---

Here is the script used to create it:

```
import csv
import sys
import subprocess

def my_test_func(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write(data)
        fd.write('\n')
    return subprocess.check_output(['evm', 'disasm', filename])

if '__main__' == __name__:

    file_name = sys.argv[1] 
    byte_code = sys.argv[2]
    status = my_test_func(file_name, byte_code)

    edits = csv.reader(status.splitlines(), delimiter=",")
    for row in edits:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Unless more examples are provided, you might get along with [**`\b[A-Z].+`**](https://regex101.com/r/WrHNJI/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just split on ':'?

```
for line in status:
    data = line.split(:)
    if len(data) < 2:
       continue
    print(data[1].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one good way:

```
opcodes_list = list()

for element in status.split('\n'):
    result = re.search(r"\b[A-Z].+", element)
    if result:
        opcodes_list.append(result.group(0))
```